# What must I do for `&rarr;` to give a trailing right arrow with the @Html.ActionLink helper method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am wondering why the follow code to create a hyperlink does not give me a trailing right arrow. What must I do for `" &rarr;"` to give a trailing arrow?

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    String.Concat("leading ", viewModel.Text.ToLower(), " &rarr;"),
    link.Key,
    link.Value)
```

Comment: http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v12/jeweleegurl/rarr.gif

Comment: Doesn't `@` automatically `HtmlEncode` everything? Why not just specify a right arrow? Your source file should be saved as UTF-8.

Comment: It's UTF-8 by default. Specifying the document to use it as follows has no effect: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best way is to go for HtmlDecode.

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    String.Concat("leading ", viewModel.Text.ToLower(), HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("&rarr;")),
    link.Key,
    link.Value)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try specifying a right arrow:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    String.Concat("leading ", viewModel.Text.ToLower(), " →"),
    link.Key,
    link.Value)
```

Comment: @Carnotaurus Why? It's `ActionLink`'s job to take what you give it and make a link ... with what you give it.

Comment: I had a look for some Microsoft source, but couldn't find it. [This was the next best thing](http://www.itorian.com/2012/12/html-encoding-in-mvc.html). *ASP.NET MVC Razor expressions are automatically HTML encoded*. Take a look at the source. You've probably got a `&rarr;` kicking around in there.

Comment: For input boxes I use "&rarr;" with no problem. So, it feels inconsistent - anyway it answers the question +1

Comment: @Carnotaurus I'm not included to look much further, considering the issue is resolved, but perhaps you can use → just fine with input boxes. I will note, however, that it depends on where you are using it. If *you* are generating the HTML, then the onus is on you to escape special characters. If *MVC* is generating the HTML, then the onus is on MVC.

Comment: Agreed - in any case, the browser page source shows the actual arrow and not the markup for the arrow. I suppose I cannot see that being a problem really as I doubt it would effect globalization.